# What's the meaning of "six words away"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning for "six words away"? I heard it repeatedly in the movie *Coach Carter*.

**Edit:** In the scene in a bus, when the coach blasts the team for sneaking out to a party without informing him, he says "you are six words away from getting kicked off the bus" or something like that.

Comment: Can you give us more context than that?

Comment: are you able to remember the context now( I hope you have seen the movie)

Comment: @RegDwight thanks for editing. My English is soo poor. Cant help it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What actually happens in *Coach Carter*:

> Coach Carter: I end up taking a road trip to the suburbs where I find my drunk ass point guard on top of Daddy's little princess!
>
> Worm: Actually, I was on the bottom, coach. She was on the top.
>
> Coach Carter: Worm, you want to be on the team? Because you're about ***six words*** from getting kicked off and kicked off this goddamn bus!

Carter is telling Worm to shut up, because what he just said made things worse.  Six is an arbitrary small number, just making the point that Worm is very close to being thrown out of the team.  *Anything* Worm says at this point could be enough to make the coach drop him.

**Edit:** just to be completely clear, this phrase isn't talking about six literal words, just that it would take dangerously little carelessness on Worm's part to get himself dropped.  The general idiom is "*N* words from *undesirable consequence*" or "*N* words away from *undesirable consequence*", where almost any small number will do for *N*.

> "You are are two words from getting thumped here!"

In the right circumstances the threat can be implied rather than specific:

> "One word.  Just one word."

The meaning is very similar to the saying, "When in a hole, stop digging."  The speaker is generally angry with the person being spoken to, and nothing that person can say with make things any better right now.

Comment: So "six words away" is not a recognizable 'set phrase' in English? Is it used anywhere else?

Comment: Google gives you a few hits.  "X words away/from Y" is an well-understood idiom for "It will take very little effort to achieve Y", but any small number will do for X.

Comment: Nice. (never heard it before) google seems to associate it either with religious things, or with the more literal finishing of a crossword puzzle. Can you add an explanation of the idiom to your answer explaining the very particular circumstances of that "six words away" instance?

Comment: @Mitch, the important thing to realise is it's an arbitrary number. OK?  **It is not a common phrase in English**.  It's just something funny! the screenwriters came up with.  You know?  Notice it's **about** six words away.  It's just funny - that's all.

Comment: @Joe Blow: Rhodri's comment "...is an well-understood idiom..." leads me to believe that it _is_ a not uncommon phrase/pattern in English. And she explained the general import of the idiom.

Comment: @Mitch: you might want to look up "Rhodri" in a dictionary of Welsh names :-)  Joe is right in that this is a pattern rather than a set phrase, but I would expect most English speakers to recognise the pattern.

Comment: @Rhodri: As an AmE speaker, I had never heard the pattern before (but that could be because of the particular number). Idiom, pattern, set phrase, snowclone...I just wanted to know if it was a 'thing' or if was made up on the spur of the moment, and I took your comment to mean that it was not made up as a nonce snowclone. Really, 'six'? LIke an acronym I was trying to come up with some well-known cutting or obscene phrase of exactly six words to match the situation. Your "One word. Just one word" is totally recognizable to me, but I didn't realize it was so easily snowcloned.

Comment: @Mitch: I've heard it used with most numbers between one and ten, in one form or another.  I must admit I thought it was an AmE usage that had spread, but I've never looked into its history.

Answer (score -1):

The [dialogue goes](http://movie.subtitlr.com/subtitle/show/93553) thus:

> Coach Carter: I end up taking a road
> trip to the suburbs where I find my
> drunk ass point guard on top of
> Daddy's little princess!
>
> Worm:
> Actually, I was on the bottom, coach.
> She was on the top.
>
> Coach Carter:
> Worm, you want to be on the team?
> Because you're about **six words** from
> getting kicked off
>
> and kicked off this
> goddamn bus!

Here Coach means **you're so close**, or rather **this close** to getting kicked off the team.

He describes this as "six words" (away) from getting kicked off. I cannot find a reference to exactly what the **six words** are;

I imagine it to be

"Get the hell off this bus" or something similar.